# (typeof Symbol !=='undefined' && Symbol.for) throw an error in IE7 and iE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, symbols, preact

Even, There is a check of **typeof Symbol !=='undefined'** which return false value in IE7/IE8 but still, somehow IE7/IE8 compiler read **Symbol.for**, might 
 be its a bug.

Can anyone help me to figure out the solution to this problem?

Actually, I am trying to run preact.js on IE7 but this line break on IE7/IE8

```
var REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE = (typeof Symbol!=='undefined' && Symbol.for && Symbol.for('react.element')) || 0xeac7;
```